# TTF_SizeText() not returning correct values for 'i' 'j' and '1' (so far discovered) in SDL2, C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I have a textbox class that works nicely with wider characters such as a,b,c... but with characters like 'f' and 'l' it seems to incorrectly get the sizing of those characters, yet correctly get the sizing of the others? Here is the code for the 'highlighting' of the text for the textbox class, its a bit long ill fix that up later, but should documented enough to understand easily.

```
void Textbox::Highlight_Text(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    if (clickedOn == true){


        int currentCharacterWidth = 0;
        int currentCharacterHeight = 0;
        int totalSize = 0;
        SDL_Rect currentCharacterRect;
        string currentCharacter, tempText;



        if (highlightedCharacters.size() >= 1){ ///To make sure only 1 thing is highlighted, in conjunction with next part
            highlighted = true;
        }

        if (highlighted == true){   /// if a part is highlighted, and is left highlighted, next time clicked, remove the highlighting and redo it
            if (EVENTS.mouseClicked == false){
                resetHighlightingNextClick = true;
            }
        }

        if (resetHighlightingNextClick == true){
            if (highlighted == true){
                if (EVENTS.mouseClicked == true){       ///actually remove the highlighting
                    highlightedCharacters.clear();
                    indexOfCharactersHighlighted.clear();
                    highlighted = false;
                    resetHighlightingNextClick = false;
                }
            }
        }



        for (int i=0; i < textboxText.Get_Text().size(); i++){
            currentCharacter =  textboxText.Get_Text()[i];
            TTF_SizeText(textboxText.fonts[textboxText.fontIndex], currentCharacter.c_str(), &currentCharacterWidth, &currentCharacterHeight);

            ///the totalSize added to rectangle is not making it wider, its adjusting its x value offset
            currentCharacterRect = {textboxText.x + totalSize, textboxText.y + int(textboxText.textSize*0.1), currentCharacterWidth, currentCharacterHeight};
            totalSize += currentCharacterWidth; ///"current" size of text in loop to get x value of specific character clicked on

            ///If mouse is touching any of the characters in the text
            if ( SDL_PointInRect(&EVENTS.mousePos, &currentCharacterRect) ){
                EVENTS.Change_Cursor(SDL_SYSTEM_CURSOR_IBEAM);

                if (EVENTS.mouseClicked == true){   ///Clicking on the text to highlight
                    if (In_Array(highlightedCharacters, currentCharacterRect.x) == false  ){
                        highlightedCharacters.push_back(currentCharacterRect);  ///If there is no duplicates
                        indexOfCharactersHighlighted.push_back(i); ///Get index of text being highlighted, its always in order too

                    }

                    if (  currentCharacterRect.x != highlightedCharacters[highlightedCharacters.size()-1].x){ ///So they don't stack up highlights, ie, you can remove them
                        /// If the mouse is not highlighting the last one, say second last on the right for example, delete the one in front of it (last one)
                        ///Like when highlighting text with mouse, it adapts to how you move it, so it unhighlights text not being highlighted
                        highlightedCharacters.pop_back();
                        indexOfCharactersHighlighted.pop_back();

                    }
                }

            }

        }///End for loop




        if (highlighted == true ){
            if (EVENTS.backspacePressed == true || EVENTS.currentKey != ""){
                tempText = textboxText.Get_Text();

                ///remove highlighted characters
                if (indexOfCharactersHighlighted.size() != 0){
                    ///the range of values highlighted will always be in a sorted order
                    tempText.erase( Min(indexOfCharactersHighlighted)  , Max(indexOfCharactersHighlighted)-Min(indexOfCharactersHighlighted)+1  );  ///erase the range of values highlighted
                    textboxText.Change_Text(renderer, tempText);

                    ///once removed text, clear every highlighted related thing
                    highlightedCharacters.clear();
                    indexOfCharactersHighlighted.clear();
                    highlighted = false;
                    resetHighlightingNextClick = false;

                    EVENTS.backspacePressed = false;
                    EVENTS.currentKey = "";
                }

            }
        }



    }   ///End if for clicked on



    ///fit with scrolling offsets
    if (EVENTS.scrolled == true){
        for (int p=0; p < highlightedCharacters.size(); p++){
            highlightedCharacters[p].y += EVENTS.scrollVal;
        }
    }




    ///Drawing the highlighted text
    if (highlighted == true   &&   clickedOn == true){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 55,60,65, 75);
        for (int j=0; j < highlightedCharacters.size(); j++){
            SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &highlightedCharacters[j]);
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(renderer, SDL_BLENDMODE_NONE);
    }


    ///when clicked off textbox, clear everything/highlighting
    if (clickedOn == false){
        highlightedCharacters.clear();
        indexOfCharactersHighlighted.clear();
        highlighted = false;
    }



}
```

For reference in the font passed in, here is how i obtain it in the text class

```
    fontIndex = textSize-lowestFontSize  -1;

    ///One time setups
    if (numOfInstances == 1){
        try{
            TTF_Init();
            //cout << "Initialised ttf" << endl;
        }
        catch (exception &err){
            cout << "Could not initialise ttf for text \"" << text << "\". Error from SDL is: " << TTF_GetError() << ". Error from C++ is: " << err.what() << endl;
        }

        for (int i=lowestFontSize; i <= highestFontSize; i++){
            TTF_Font *currentFont = TTF_OpenFont(fontType.c_str(), i);
            if (!currentFont){
                cout << "Error with font in text \"" << txt << "\" Error is: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
            }

            fonts.push_back(currentFont);
        }

    }
```

and so if i pass in, say 25 as my text size, i have my lowestFontSize = 10 and highestFontSize = 100, so the index i need for size 25 would be (25-10 -1 = 14), as indexing begins at 0, which is that first line before i create my static vector of fonts in the text class. Here is a snippet of what i'm trying to explain:

[image]

This is clearly working properly.

[image]

But now, it is completely inaccurate. If i select a random character towards the end of the text, it is not correctly highlighted, only from the beginning the first one looks pretty much perfect, but then it seems as if the inaccuracy is compounded, hence making the total grey highlighting much wider than it is supposed to be.

Comment: I'd just like to add to this, after testing some things out, ONLY (so far) the letter 'f' and number '1' seem to make this problem, things like 'l' and 'i' and 't' don't seem to cause any issues. Very weird.

Comment: Also, would like to add, after displaying the character sizes (in font 50), the width of the letter 'j' is 17, whereas 'f' is 20? And if i display 96 f's, (which is supposed to be 1920 wide and fill up my screen, it doesnt. I need about 110 to fill my display. Also, the number '1' is 35 wide alongside 'a' which is also 35 wide. It seems that the letters 'f' and number '1' do not return correct sizing from SDL2

Comment: Don't know how to edit my last comment, It's actually wrong, 'j' is also incorrect i think its 'i' that is, but 'j' 'f' and '1' have problems (atleast those are the ones ive discovered so far)

Comment: You seem to assume that the width of a string must be equal to the sum of widths of individual characters. This is an incorrect assumption. Google "kerning".

Comment: It doesn't look like the characters overlap, but lets assume they do, how do i fix this? I have tried TTF_SetFontKerning() as true and false, it makes no difference.

Comment: Actually it does, it makes a small gap between the 'f's but that now compounds the problem even more

Comment: You just never add up widths of individual characters. This operation is meaningless.

Comment: How else would i do highlighting when i click onto the text? The way i do it is drawing the rectangle of each individual character HIGHLIGHTED then the following character's x location is the previous characters + its width. I don't know any other way of doing this. The code for how i do it is in the question if you want to have a look at.

Comment: of course if i wanted to highlight the text entirely, i would just pass in the entire string, but if i only want to highlight say the middle 3 characters of a string, which currently i CAN, i dont know any other way for achieving that.

Comment: You query the width of the entire string. A character is only meaningful as an element of a string. If you have a string "xyzt" and you want to highlight the "z", you query the width of "xy" and the width of "xyz", that would be the start and the end of "z".

Comment: ok, so rather than doing the TTF_SizeText, i query the characters instead? But i need the texture of the text, which is also the texture of the ENTIRE string drawn to the screen, rather, not the individual characters. I sort of see what youre saying, but it seems like it requires new surfaces and textures and fonts to be loaded just to find the width of 2 characters.

Comment: I don't quite understand how to do what youre suggesting sorry, i can only see query with textures or a constant in SDL. Also im still confused why it doesn't work with kerning off for only SPECIFIC letters (i,1,f) yet works perfectly for the rest of them..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You just call TTF_SizeText twice, to fund where your selected portion starts and ends. You probably don't want to turn kerning off, ever.

Comment: Oh, i got you now, yeah okay thanks. So from the text "abcdefg" if i want the size of "f" ill do TTF_SizeText(font, "abcdef", w,h) and then TTF_SizeText(font, "abcde", w2,h2) and then the width of "f" is w-w2 right?

Comment: I just tried this method in a simple program, it worked.

Comment: No, I take it back, it doesn't work with all characters.

Comment: Made it work ;) You need to measure the width of the prefix (text before selection), the width of the selection, and the width of both together. The first two will not add up to the third, the difference is the correction you need to apply to rectangle.x of the highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your method is that individual character widths are meaningless. The renderer adjusts them depending on context (their neighbours in the rendered string). So the width of `i` in the rendered string `bit` is not necessarily the same as the width of `i` in the rendered string `fil`.

The method to find text selection coordinates needs to take context into account.

Say we have the width of the three strings:

- `prefixWidth` is the size of the prefix (the original line of text up to but not including the selection)
- `selWidth` is the width of the selection itself
- `totalWidth` is the width of the prefix and the selection concatenated

(we don't care about the portion after the selection). The first two widths will be close to the third, but will not add up because of the kerning between the last character of the prefix and the first character of the selection. The difference is the correction you need to apply to the X coordinate of the rendered selection. So we need to start rendering selection at the X coordinate which is not `prefixWidth`, but

```
prefixWidth + (totalWidth - (prefixWidth + selWidth))
```

which is the same as

```
totalWidth - selWidth
```

so you don't really need to calculate prefixWidth at all.

A full (semi-)working example program below. The arguments are (1) font file full path (2) font size (3) string to render (4) selection start (5) selection length. The selection is rendered on top of the original text, shifted 1 pixel down and right, so it is easy to see if there is any deviation.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char* substr(const char* src, int fromChar, int subLen)
{
    if (subLen < 0 || fromChar < 0 || fromChar + subLen > (int)strlen(src))
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "invalid substring\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* z = (char*)malloc(subLen);
    strncpy(z, src + fromChar, subLen);
    z[subLen] = '\0';
    return z;
}

void textExtent(TTF_Font* font, const char* text,
                int fromChar, int subLen, int* w, int* h)
{
    int l = strlen(text);
    if (subLen == -1) subLen = l;
    if (fromChar < 0 || subLen > l)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Bad text extent\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* z = substr(text, fromChar, subLen);

    TTF_SizeUTF8(font, z, w, h);

    free(z);
}

int textWidth(TTF_Font* font, const char* text,
    int fromChar, int subLen)
{
    int w, h;
    textExtent(font, text, fromChar, subLen, &w, &h);
    return w;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    TTF_Init();

    if (argc != 6)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "usage: %s font text from length\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    const char* fontpath = argv[1];
    int fontSz = atoi(argv[2]);
    const char* txt = argv[3];
    int from = atoi(argv[4]);
    int len = atoi(argv[5]);

    int tsize = strlen(txt);
    if (from < 0 || from + len >= tsize)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Invalid text portion to highlight\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (fontSz < 2 || fontSz > 300)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Invalid font size\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // open font to render with

    TTF_Font * font = TTF_OpenFont(fontpath, fontSz);
    if (!font)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not open font %s\n", fontpath);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Query text size
    int textW, textH;
    textExtent(font, txt, 0, -1, &textW, &textH);

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL_ttf in SDL2",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, textW, textH, 0);

    // Query selection coords
    //
    int selWidth = textWidth(font, txt, from, len);
    int totalWidth = textWidth(font, txt, 0, from+len);

    // Render portions of text

    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Color color = { 255, 128, 0, 0 };
    SDL_Surface * surface = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, txt, color);
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_Texture * texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);

    SDL_Rect dstrect = { 0, 0, textW, textH };

    SDL_Color color2 = { 0, 128, 255, 128 };

    char* s = substr(txt, from, len);
    SDL_Surface * surface2 = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font, s, color2);
    free(s);
    SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode(surface, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_Texture * texture2 = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface2);
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(texture2, 128);
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(texture2, SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
    SDL_Rect dstrect2 = {totalWidth - selWidth + 1, 1, selWidth, textH };

    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);

        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &dstrect);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture2, NULL, &dstrect2);

        //Update screen
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
    TTF_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that actually works really nicely, Thanks! There is only a small problem that probably has an easy fix i just cant seem to get my head around it. As the rectangles are complete/adapt to the kerning and represent the rendered sizes, the rectangles drawn overlap highlighting, so for 'f's i get a DARKER shade where they overlap, rather a smooth-same colour highlighting.

Comment: I think i have an idea, ill have to redo the function, but rather than individual rectangles, just make ONE rectangle that has all the highlighted characters in it. fingers crossed!

Comment: Just a small edit, this doesn't work with special characters, unrecognised ones i mean. Since i get input if a key is pressed, pressing the windows key prints some weird looking 'a' and it doesnt get its width correctly, but that doesn't really matter since its not exactly a valid input

Comment: Ok, sorry just one last thing. This method works nicely, however your substr version, vs using strings, and str.substr() work similarly in performance, but as the text gets alot longer the performance really and i mean really starts to dip, i go from like 10k fps, down to about 2k after only 1 display width of letters. It seems if i want alot more of these its going to eventually make the performance so bad its unusable. Do you have any ideas how to make it better?

Comment: @PeterWilson I have no idea why I would want 2k fps, let alone 10k, when showing different text in each frame. You need to recalculate the widths only if your displayed string or your selection range change. But if you really need this, you can optimize "substr" by modifying the original string destructively (write `'\0'` where you want it to end) and then restoring it after size calculations.

Comment: Okay, possibly that might work but i am a bit confused on some things. If i want to highlight the text with my mouse, wouldn't i have to recalculate the widths as the string will change and the rectangle that stimulates 'grey' will change accordingly to the mouse, so only if it is clicked? But even then when its highlighted it still drops a bunch.

Comment: For the fps part, yes i completely get it, 10k is overkill, so is 2k. But i am trying to make the code run as fast as possible so that when there are intensive tasks that i can't optimize and will take a large portion of time (ie, searching), i have as much fps to work with that it still runs smoothly. 2k is OVERKILL, but if you think about it, just the single substr method in the for loop of the highlighted method is making the code run 5 TIMES slower, with a string now double the length of the one i am using, it will run 10x slower, ie, now 1000 fps and thats just for a simple textbox

Comment: For the substr, i tried using strings for it and the "myString.substr()" runs quite a bit faster than the char* substr, however, so I am wondering if the substr string method actually utilises the "\0" to optimize it, either way i will try that, but i think i'd need a better way for finding what characters to highlight due to mouse inputs than i currently have, that way i wouldn't need to iterate through the entire string whilst using substr.

Comment: Oh, also, the 2k fps or 10k fps doesn't matter for my text display, because when i scroll, my event handling maintains the timing that is on windows when inputting text (ie, when you hold down a key, it types it once, then waits, then spams it) rather than it printing out say  the "a" key 10000 times when i press it for a second as due to the fps. Its just there as a measure and i will use vsync when i am done as i dont need that much fps i agree. It is just for benchmarking as i make it